# Move child object according to parent

Tags: modeling

I need to have a cube (the BLUE one) to be linked to a parent (the RED one).
So when I move the RED cube from the ground the BLUE cube shall move in the same direction proportionally.

How to make this kind of link in Blender?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give your blue cube a *Transformation* constraint with the red cube as *Target*:

[image]

Enable the *Extrapolate* option. In the XYZ fields, choose the values you want, it will determine the ratio. If you choose -10/10 and -10/-10, the blue cube will move as much as the red cube on the given axis. If you choose -10/10 and -20/-20, the blue cube will move twice the distance of the red cube:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This way looks quite flexible.

Comment: unrelated question: What tool are you using for making animated screencaps?

Comment: I'm using ScreenToGif  ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Copy location constraint.**

[image]

- Red is parent of Blue.  Both at same location.
- Blue is given delta location Z to offset it from Red.  Could use Z location
- A copy location constraint is added to Blue to Map the global Z location of Red to it's local location.  Check use offset to use the delta Z location set above.
- Note this all works well until the Parent is transformed, at which case the spaces no longer match.

Comment: unrelated question: What tool are you using for making animated screencaps?

Comment: @MartyFouts https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: @p2or thanks.  I was just being curious about which of the various available tools people were using.  I use ScreenToGif myself; but I'm usually too lazy to do it for an answer.